# cloudfoundry eclipse plugin behind a proxy

Tags: eclipse, plugins, proxy, cloud-foundry

how can I connect to cloudfoundry using the STS Plugin when I am behind a proxy? The plugin seems to be unaware of my Network Eclipse proxy settings, and when I validate my account or connect, I get an I/O error or unable to connect to api.cloudfoundry.com.

I am quite sure it is the proxy it does not know about (it somehow is an issue with any kind of development, Maven, Grails and consorts).

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, did you try configure the system proxy and select direct connect in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

so I don't know about actual proxy support, but while searching our JIRA for "proxy", I came accross those two : https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2975 and https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2872.

You may have a look at them, as they seem to imply that this is supported somehow.

From [this](https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-cloudfoundry/blob/master/org.cloudfoundry.ide.eclipse.server.tests/src/org/cloudfoundry/ide/eclipse/server/tests/sts/util/ProxyHandler.java), I assume there is proxy support as well. I just haven't had time to figure it out.

Sorry for such a half response, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In **Eclipse preferences > General/Network Preferences,**

Use Manual proxy provider (not Native), and set your proxy for both HTTP and HTTPS.